# How to hide/show a bootstrap pulldown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pulldown that I want to be initially hidden.  When I click a + button, I want the pulldown to be shown.   The bug I'm having is that the call to .show only flashes the pulldown.  It doesn't stay exposed:

fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/marshall62/nj783tbr/
Generates some kind of POST error after click on plus but you get the idea of what I'm trying to do...

Javascript (w Jquery + bootstrap)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').hide();
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
            $('#add-strategy').click(function ()  {
                $('.dropdown-toggle').show();
            });

        });
```

HTML

```
<a id="add-strategy" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a> Click Plus to add a strategy

<div id="strategy-pulldown"  class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                ----
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

                    <li><a href="#">strategy a</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">strategy b</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">strategy c</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `preventDefault` method. You are using an anchor which is causing the page to reload. You need to prevent this by using the below code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').hide();
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
            $('#add-strategy').click(function (e)  {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.dropdown-toggle').show();
            });

        });
```